# KendoUI Stacked Bar Chart Custom Tooltip

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have a rather simple stacked bar chart.  You can see it in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Grandizer/9jp6879m/1/). My series is as follows:

```
"series" : [{
    "name" : "HearingOfficer - Scheduling",
    "color" : "",
    "times" : ["Top Row Orange", "Bottom Row Orange"],
    "data" : [126716, 107910]
  }, {
    "name" : "HearingOfficer - Uploading",
    "color" : "",
    "times" : ["Top Row Green", "Bottom Row Green"],
    "data" : [10930, 106554]
  }
],
```

Right now, when I hover over the TOP ORANGE section it should say `Hearing Officer - Scheduling Top - Row Orange`.  When I hover over the TOP GREEN section it should say `Hearing Officer - Uploading - Top Row Green`.

It has the Top Orange section good.  But the Top Green says Bottom Green.  The Bottom row duplicates the tooltips of the first row.

Is there a way to correctly show the appropriate values.  My current tooltip template is:

```
"template" : "#= series.name #<br />#= series.times[series.index] #"
```

I thought I noticed `series.index` work but it always returns 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to deal with the same problem a couple of weeks ago and I solved my problem by using dataSource instead of defining each series.  It's implementation is a bit more complex but this will give you a lot of control over each element of the chart.

For instance, you'll be able to set all kind of custom values to a dataItem (including a text that could be used as a tooltip).  Those values can be used from the tooltip template like this:

```
template: "#= dataItem.myCustomToolTip #"
```

**EDIT**

Here's a [full example](http://jsfiddle.net/simonbesner/15x8t3a4/1/) of the dataSource implementation.  Please note that the dataSource is very picky when you deal with the Sort / Group.  The dataSource will group correctly only if data is sorted in the expected order (in this example, it has to be sorted by category then by subCategory).

```
$("#chartBreakout").kendoChart({
    title: { "text" : "Breakdown per Appeal" },
    legend: { "visible" : false },
    dataSource: {
        data: [
            {categoryOrder: 1, categoryName: "HearingOfficer - Scheduling", subCategoryOrder: 1, subCategoryName: "Orange", value: 126716},
            {categoryOrder: 1, categoryName: "HearingOfficer - Scheduling", subCategoryOrder: 2, subCategoryName: "Green", value: 10930},
            {categoryOrder: 2, categoryName: "HearingOfficer - Uploading", subCategoryOrder: 1, subCategoryName: "Orange", value: 107910},
            {categoryOrder: 2, categoryName: "HearingOfficer - Uploading", subCategoryOrder: 2, subCategoryName: "Green", value: 106554}
        ],
        group: {
            field: "subCategoryOrder",
            dir: "asc"
        },
        sort: [
            { field: "categoryOrder", dir: "asc" },
            { field: "subCategoryOrder", dir: "asc" }
        ]
    },
    seriesDefaults: {
        type: "bar",
        stack: { type: "normal" }
    },
    series: [{
        type: "bar",
        field: "value"
    }],
    valueAxis: {
        line: { visible: false },
        majorGridLines: {
            visible: true
        }
    },
    categoryAxis: {
        field: "categoryName"
    },
    tooltip: {
        visible: true,
        template: "#= dataItem.categoryName# - #= dataItem.subCategoryName# : #= dataItem.value#"
    }    
});
```

Comment: Thanks @The_Black_Smurf for the heads up.  I can not get back to this project for about a week.  Is there any chance you update the fiddle to show this?

Comment: @Grandizer, I updated my answer with a working example of what you are trying to do.